# Environment variables and further user setup

Tags: user-management, users, java

I have a jar file, which *works* in many machines. However we just asked for a new unix user to install it, and it is not behaving the same... wonder if it could be anything related to some env. var.

the basic idea is:

```
WorkingUser@box$ java -jar install.jar -h
[output help instructions]
```

but then

```
NewUser@box$ java -jar install.jar -h
The java class is not found:  pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.Loader
```

Before anyone asks, there is no classpath needed and yes, the cksum for the jar is ok. in fact:

```
$ jar tf install.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
pkg1/
pkg1/pkg2/
pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/
pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/script/
pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/Loader.class
pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/LoaderHelper.class
package.jar
```

And you can figure that the `MANIFEST.MF` is fine, since it works in other users.

I have tried executing with `-cp install.jar` with no success. Also the `$CLASSPATH` for working and not working users contains only "`.`".

**[EDIT]**

I seem to have found more weird things on this new user. There are few other things not working which may indicate a problem with the user creation. Unfortunately I don't know to much of user administration in AIX, so I hope you guys can help me to figure out from these leads;

I have just found that simple `tar` cannot be created into this user's home.

```
NewUser@box$ echo "thisisatest" > testfile.txt
NewUser@box$ tar cf testfile.txt.tar testfile.txt
tar: The getwd subroutine failed.
        Cannot open the parent directory.

NewUser@box$ ls -l testfile*
-rw-r-----    1 user  group             12 Feb 08 14:15 testfile.txt
-rw-r-----    1 user  group              0 Feb 08 14:15 testfile.txt.tar
```

(Notice how `testfile.txt.tar` has **0** bytes?)

Needless to say, all these commands works on the other user.

Apart from that, there's another small symptom regards connecting with `scp`, `WinSpc` actually.

The connection wont work yielding the following error at first:
[image: scp error without configuring it]

To correct this error, I simply have to configure `remote path` in WinScp's configuration (which apparently defines the path to the user home) and it will work fine.

I use WinScp in the other server and it works just fine without any configuration - I ignored this error at first, but now seems more relevant.

Note that `/etc/passwd` has all the correct parameters for this user. It might be some *dodgier* configuration...

Also, the home folder has all the correct permissions - I'm not to sure how that "sticky bit" relates to it, but.. well..

Thanks in advance!

thanks,

f.

Comment: Are java versions the same for old and new users? You can check using `java -version`.

Comment: yep. they are... same build actually.

Comment: Can you run it under strace? strace java -jar install.jar and post the output (might be big!)

Comment: do that in a jiffy, meanwhile you might want to check the new info I just added. thanks!

Comment: OK. It's AIX so I don't think you will have strace (unless it has some Linux utilities installed). Check if you have a command called "truss". I don't know if AIX has that.

Comment: Try copying the file to /tmp or /var/tmp and running the install from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying the file to /tmp or /var/tmp and running the install from there. Does it get further/succeed?

**[EDIT]**

This was pretty close to the actual problem. I ended up doing a similar test which worked and  which with some testing lead me to find that the *mount point* permissions were wrong, i.e. the folder where the user's fs is mounted belongs to *root* and had access `774` (no exec to *others*).

I find always fascinating how wrong permissions in a low level cause the most adverse effects in the upper layers. I had (and I'm still not quite sure of it) that the permissions of the mount point had affect the mounted fs...

Anyways, we gave it the exec permission and *voilá*, java finds it's classes. There are more problems with this whole installation, but these might go to other questions :)

Thanks all.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Quite a good call it got me very close to the actual problem. If you don't mind I'll edit you post and mark as the answer.